# objective-c initializer in memory-management environment

Tags: iphone

So I'm trying to write an initializer for a subclass of NSOperation.  This is my first time using NSOperation.  My NSOperation subclass looks like this:

```
.h
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *fileName;

.m
@synthesize fileName = _fileName;


- (id)initWitFileName:(NSString *)fileName  {
    if (self = [super init]) {
        _fileName = fileName;
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)dealloc {
    [_fileName release];
    [super dealloc];
}

- (void)main {
  // do long task
}
```

So I thought when I create my own initializers, I should just set the ivar myself since the state of the object is undetermined in the init method.  So I don't use the accessor in the initializer.  When my main method gets run, I get a memory bad access and a crash.  However, in my init method, if I do this instead:

```
- (id)initWitFileName:(NSString *)fileName  {
        if (self = [super init]) {
            _fileName = [fileName retain];
        }
        return self;
    }
```

I do not get a crash.  What is correct?  I'd think in this second case that I wouldn't be releasing the memory since the accessor is (copy).  Or is it because I don't use the accessor, that my fileName object basically gets dealloc'd only since there is no +1 in the initWithFileName method?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you `@synthesize` something with a set of properties, you're generating getters and setters for the object. This allows you to use methods like

```
[self setFilename:@"MyFile.txt"]
```

or

```
self.filename = @"MyFile.txt"
```

Both of the lines above function in exactly the same way, and might be implemented like this:

```
- (void)setFilename:(NSString *)string {
    _filename = [string copy];
    // Or, for a retained property:
    // _filename = [string retain];
}
```

This implementation is overly simplified. See idz's comment below for a better understanding of the logic that a real setter would use.

---

In your example above, you're simply using the `=` operator, and not a generated function.

```
_fileName = fileName;
```

Because of this, you're simply setting the address of `_fileName` to `fileName`. None of your `synthesize` properties matter, and don't make a difference here.

Your explanation:

> Is it because I don't use the accessor, that my fileName object basically gets dealloc'd only since there is no +1 in the initWithFileName method?

is exactly correct. To properly replicate the `copy` property used by your synthesizer, use this:

```
_fileName = [fileName copy];
```

Comment: Your setter isn't quite right; It would leak. You need to release the existing setting taking care to handle the situation where the new value and old value are the same. So the retain case the sequence is: `[string retain]; [_filename release]; _filename = string;`. For copy it is `NSString* copy = [string copy]; [_filename release]; _filename = copy;`

Answer (score 1):

The second one is close, but:

```
- (id)initWitFileName:(NSString *)fileName  
{
    if (self = [super init]) {
        _fileName = [fileName copy];
    }
    return self;
}
```

is more usual since `NSString*` properties are generally defined with `(nonatomic, copy)`.

This is done to avoid problems or unintended consequences if the caller is actually passing a `NSMutableString` and later changes the value.

Answer (score 0):

Idea 1: Use ARC. In ARC, you'd declare your ivar strong, and then either use the synthesized setter or assign the ivar directly. A retain will be added for you and all will be well.

Idea 2: Use retain. If you're unable to use ARC for some reason, why you don't declare the NSString as retain, instead of copy? It's okay to hold onto the same instance of an immutable thing. (Sharing a mutable thing can be useful, too, as long as both classes understand that they are doing that).

Idea 3: If you must use non-arc and you must use copy, set the ivar with copy. That will fix your crash by doing the copy. As it is now, the code is copying the handle to the passed string, but not it's contents. The passed string is dealloc'd and your class is stuck with a zombie. You can say _filename = [string copy]; as others have suggested.

As a side-note, calling self = [super init]; is correct inside the overridden init method. Since you're making your own init variant, I think it's more proper to call self = [self init];